# What is the best way to support multiple .net versions in nuget package?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I have read the section in the nuget docs that explain you can put dependencies under /lib/ and those will apply to just that framework. So /lib/net40, /lib45, etc.  I believe this will create a package that will support both .net 4 and .net 4.5 platforms.  I have also read about people creating specific builds for each .net version. What is the best practice here and where do you define these mixed version libraries? (in the nuspec file by creating Groups or in the packages.config by setting targetFramework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed in this article.  There is a marriage between msbuild/xbuild and nuget that needs to exists in order for the nuget package to be created in the folder structure I mentioned above. Basically, your .csproj file is a msbuild script. And in this script, you tell it what Configurations will be supported.  Let's say that your have a Configuration to perform a .net40 build and one for .net45.  You then need to build the project twice with each configuration, before you can create your nuget package. It is all explained here:

http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/05/29/automating-creating-nuget-packages-with-msbuild/